# Two cards inside div, width is not equal

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have two two divs inside a main div. Each div contains a card. The problem is, the second div & card are not the same width as the first one. I tried setting 'col-12' on `<div class="card panel-info mb-4">` and it works but then the card header style breaks. I'm using bootstrap 4. Why is the second div not fully stretched?

[image]

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form id="dataOnTab" role="form" class="form-horizontal details-content" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <input type="hidden" id="SelectedTabForSave" name="SelectedTabForSave" value="@RegisterBookTabs.FamilyCustodyView" />

  <div class="container" style="max-width:100% ;">
    <div class="row voffset4">
      <div class="col-md-12 column">
        <div class="card panel-info mb-4">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h6 class="card-title">
              @SharedResources.Index.WorkAbility
            </h6>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group row col-6">
                <label for="WorkAbilityID" class="col-sm-4 text-right control-label">@SharedResources.Index.WorkAbility</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <select class="form-control input-sm" id="WorkAbilityID" data-bind="
                                    value: workAbilityID,
                                    options: workAbilityIDSelectList,
                                    optionsText: 'Text' ,
                                    optionsValue: 'Value' "></select>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group row col-6">
                <label for="SocialWelfareCenter" class="col-sm-4 text-right control-label">@SharedResources.Index.SocialWelfareCenter</label>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="socialWelfareCenter-error" data-bind="value: socialWelfareCenter">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row voffset4">
      <div class="card panel-info mb-4">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h6 class="card-title">
            @SharedResources.Index.FamilyAndCustody
          </h6>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
              <div id="family-custudy-grid-container" class="knockout">
                <table id="mDataTable" data-cols-num="5" class="table" aria-describedby="mDataTable_info">
                  <thead>
                    <tr class="search-cols" style="display: none;" role="row"></tr>
                    <tr class="actions-row" role="row">
                      <td class="header-action-row" style="border:none; cursor:default;" colspan="11">
                        <h6 class='datatable-title'><span class='fa fa-list'></span>&nbsp; @SharedResources.Index.FamilyAndCustody</h6>
                        <div class="action-images pull-right">
                          <div class="add-img fa fa-plus-circle" style="cursor:pointer;" title="@SharedResources.Index.Add" data-bind="click: Editable ? mainDataAdd : null, css:{'icon-disabled':  Editable == false}"></div>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                      <th style="width: 20%;" data-bind="click: function () {mainDataRefreshData(1,3)}, css: mainDataFirstNameIcon">@SharedResources.Index.Firstname</th>
                      <th style="width: 20%;" data-bind="click: function () {mainDataRefreshData(1,2)}, css: mainDataLastNameIcon">@SharedResources.Index.Lastname</th>
                      <th style="width: 16%;" data-bind="click: function () {mainDataRefreshData(1,4)}, css: mainDataRelationNameIcon">@SharedResources.Index.RelationName</th>
                      <th style="width: 8%;" data-bind="click: function () {mainDataRefreshData(1,8)}, css: mainDataDocumentURNumberIcon">@SharedResources.Index.DocumentURNumber</th>
                      <th style="width: 8%;" data-bind="click: function () {mainDataRefreshData(1,9)}, css: mainDataPhoneNumberIcon">@SharedResources.Index.PhoneNumber</th>
                      <th style="width: 8%;" data-bind="click: function () {mainDataRefreshData(1,10)}, css: mainDataCellPhoneNumberIcon">@SharedResources.Index.CellPhoneNumber</th>
                      <th style="width: 6%;" data-bind="click: function () {mainDataRefreshData(1,5)}, css: mainDataCCustodyIndicatorIcon">@SharedResources.Index.CustodyIndicator</th>
                      <th style="width: 6%;" data-bind="click: function () {mainDataRefreshData(1,6)}, css: mainDataEmergencyNotificationIcon">@SharedResources.Index.EmergencyNotification</th>
                      <th style="width: 6%;" data-bind="click: function () {mainDataRefreshData(1,7)}, css: mainDataFuneralNotificationIcon">@SharedResources.Index.FuneralNotification</th>

                      <th></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tr data-bind="visible: mainData() == null || mainData().length < 1">
                    <td data-bind="attr: { 'colspan': 11 }">
                      <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert"> @SharedResources.Index.NoData</div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tbody data-bind="foreach: mainData">
                    <tr style="cursor:pointer;" data-bind="click :$parent.mainDataSelectRow.bind($data,$index()),
                        css: { 'row-selected': $parent.mainDataSelectedRowPosition() != null && $index() == $parent.mainDataSelectedRowPosition() && ForDelete() == false , 'for-delete': ForDelete() == true}">
                      <td data-bind="text: Firstname, click: Editable ? $root.mainDataDetails : null, attr : {'disabled' : ForDelete}  "></td>
                      <td data-bind="text: Lastname, click: Editable ? $root.mainDataDetails : null, attr : {'disabled' : ForDelete} "> </td>
                      <td data-bind="text: RelationName, click: Editable ? $root.mainDataDetails : null, attr : {'disabled' : ForDelete}  "></td>
                      <td data-bind="text: DocumentURNumber, click: Editable ? $root.mainDataDetails : null, attr : {'disabled' : ForDelete}  "></td>
                      <td data-bind="text: PhoneNumber, click: Editable ? $root.mainDataDetails : null, attr : {'disabled' : ForDelete}  "></td>
                      <td data-bind="text: CellPhoneNumber, click: Editable ? $root.mainDataDetails : null, attr : {'disabled' : ForDelete}  "></td>
                      <td data-bind="text: CustodyIndicator, click: Editable ? $root.mainDataDetails : null, attr : {'disabled' : ForDelete}  "></td>
                      <td data-bind="text: EmergencyNotification, click: Editable ? $root.mainDataDetails : null, attr : {'disabled' : ForDelete}  "></td>
                      <td data-bind="text: FuneralNotification, click: Editable ? $root.mainDataDetails : null, attr : {'disabled' : ForDelete}  "></td>

                      <td class="action-column">
                        <div class="row-delete fa fa-share icon-flip" title="@SharedResources.Index.Undo" style="color: #096224; cursor: pointer;" data-bind="click: $parent.mainDataUndoRemove, visible: ForDelete() == true"></div>
                        <div class="row-delete fa fa-minus-circle icon-delete" title="@SharedResources.Index.Delete" data-bind="click: (CanDelete() == true && $parent.active() != 3) && ($parent.isChangedCfm() == false && Editable) ? $parent.mainDataRemove: null, visible: ForDelete() == false,
                                                                           css:{'icon-disabled':  (CanDelete() == false && $parent.active() != 3) ||  $parent.isChangedCfm() == true  ||  Editable == false }" style="color: #9E0101;cursor: pointer;"></div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <ul class="pagination pagination-sm" style="margin: 0">
                      <li data-bind="css: { disabled:  mainDataCurrentPage() == 1 }, visible: mainDataTotalPages() > 0" class="page-link disabled">
                        <a data-bind="click: mainDataCurrentPage() > 1 ? mainDataRefreshData.bind($data, 1, null) : null, style: { cursor: mainDataCurrentPage() == 1 ? 'not-allowed' : 'pointer' }">&laquo;</a>
                      </li>
                      <li data-bind="css: { disabled:  mainDataCurrentPage() == 1 }, visible: mainDataTotalPages() > 0" class="page-link disabled">
                        <a data-bind="click: mainDataCurrentPage() > 1 ? mainDataRefreshData.bind($data, mainDataCurrentPage()-1, null) : null, style: { cursor: mainDataCurrentPage() == 1 ? 'not-allowed' : 'pointer' }">&lsaquo;</a>
                      </li>
                      <!-- ko foreach: new Array(mainDataTotalPages()) -->
                      <li class="page-item" data-bind="css: { active:  $index()+1 == $parent.mainDataCurrentPage() }, visible: $index()+1 < $parent.mainDataCurrentPage()+3 && $index()+1 > $parent.mainDataCurrentPage()-3">
                        <a href="#" class="page-link" data-bind="text: $index()+1, click: $parent.mainDataRefreshData.bind($data,$index()+1, null)"></a>
                      </li>
                      <!-- /ko -->
                      <li data-bind="css: { disabled:  mainDataCurrentPage() == mainDataTotalPages() }, visible: mainDataTotalPages() > 0 " class="page-link">
                        <a data-bind="click: mainDataCurrentPage() < mainDataTotalPages() ? mainDataRefreshData.bind($data, mainDataCurrentPage()+1, null) : null, style: { cursor: mainDataCurrentPage() == mainDataTotalPages() ? 'not-allowed' : 'pointer' }">&rsaquo;</a>
                      </li>
                      <li data-bind="css: { disabled:  mainDataCurrentPage() == mainDataTotalPages() }, visible: mainDataTotalPages() > 0 " class="page-link">
                        <a data-bind="click: mainDataCurrentPage() < mainDataTotalPages() ? mainDataRefreshData.bind($data, mainDataTotalPages(), null) : null, style: { cursor: mainDataCurrentPage() == mainDataTotalPages() ? 'not-allowed' : 'pointer' }">&raquo;</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <span class="pull-right"> @SharedResources.Index.Record <span data-bind="text: mainDataTotalItems"></span> </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    @if (User.IsInRole(AppRole.AdmissionService.ToString()) || User.IsInRole(AppRole.SocialWorker.ToString()) || User.IsInRole(AppRole.HeadNurse.ToString()) || User.IsInRole(AppRole.DepartmentNurse.ToString())) {
    <div class="row voffset4">
      <div class="card panel-info mb-4">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h6 class="card-title">
            @SharedResources.Index.ContactWithFamilyMembers
          </h6>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <h6 class="subtitle"><span class="fa fa-search"></span> @SharedResources.Index.Filter</h6>
              <div id="search-holder">
                <div id="search-box">
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-9 col-sm-9 row">
                      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-6">
                        <input id="searchResident" type="text" class="form-control search-input" data-bind="value: contactWithFamilySearchTerm, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', enterkey: contactWithFamilyRefreshData" placeholder="@SharedResources.Index.SearchMessage" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3">
                        <input id="searchDateStart" type="text" class="form-control search-input searching-date-from-to picker" data-bind="datePicker: contactWithFamilySearchDateFrom, maxDate: contactWithFamilySearchDateTo, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', enterkey: contactWithFamilyRefreshData"
                          placeholder="@SharedResources.Index.SearchDateFrom" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3">
                        <input id="searchDateEnd" type="text" class="form-control search-input searching-date-from-to picker" data-bind="datePicker: contactWithFamilySearchDateTo, minDate: contactWithFamilySearchDateFrom, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', enterkey: contactWithFamilyRefreshData"
                          placeholder="@SharedResources.Index.SearchDateTo" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                      <button type="button" id="search" class="btn btn-newline" data-bind="click: function() {contactWithFamilyRefreshData()}"> @SharedResources.Index.Search</button>
                      <button class="btn btn-sm leftmargin10" title="@SharedResources.Index.Reset" data-bind="click: function() {contactWithFamilyResetSearch()}">
                                                <span class="fa fa-repeat"></span>
                                            </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="contact-with-family-members" class="knockout">
                <table id="mDataTable" data-cols-num="5" class="table" aria-describedby="mDataTable_info">
                  <thead>
                    <tr class="search-cols" style="display: none;" role="row"></tr>
                    <tr class="actions-row" role="row">
                      <td class="header-action-row" style="border:none; cursor:default;" colspan="11">
                        <h6 class='datatable-title'><span class='fa fa-list'></span>&nbsp; @SharedResources.Index.ContactWithFamilyMembers</h6>
                        <div class="action-images pull-right">
                          <div class="add-img fa fa-plus-circle" style="cursor:pointer;" title="@SharedResources.Index.Add" data-bind="click: newItemAdded() == false && mainDataTotalItems() != 0 && Editable && active != 3 ? contactWithFamilyAdd : null, css:{'icon-disabled':newItemAdded() == true || mainDataTotalItems() == 0 || Editable == false || active == 3}, style:{cursor: newItemAdded() == false && mainDataTotalItems() != 0 ?'pointer' :'not-allowed' }"></div>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th style="width: 22%;" data-bind="click: function () {contactWithFamilyRefreshData(1,1)}, css: userIcon">@SharedResources.Index.ContactedPerson</th>
                      <th style="width: 22%;" data-bind="click: function () {contactWithFamilyRefreshData(1,2)}, css: dateOfContactIcon">@SharedResources.Index.DateOfContact</th>
                      <th style="width: 22%;" data-bind="click: function () {contactWithFamilyRefreshData(1,3)}, css: timeOfContactIcon">@SharedResources.Index.TimeOfContact</th>
                      <th style="width: 12%;" data-bind="click: function () {contactWithFamilyRefreshData(1,4)}, css: employeeIcon">@SharedResources.Index.Employee</th>
                      <th style="width: 22%;" data-bind="click: function () {contactWithFamilyRefreshData(1,5)}, css: remarkIcon">@SharedResources.Index.Remark</th>
                      <th></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tr data-bind="visible: contactWithFamily() == null || contactWithFamily().length < 1">
                    <td data-bind="attr: { 'colspan': 11 }">
                      <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert"> @SharedResources.Index.NoData</div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tbody data-bind="foreach: contactWithFamily">
                    <tr style="cursor: pointer;" data-bind="click :$parent.contactWithFamilySelectRow.bind($data,$index()),
                                                css: { 'row-selected': $parent.contactWithFamilySelectedRowPosition() != null && $index() == $parent.contactWithFamilySelectedRowPosition() && ForDelete() == false, 'for-delete': ForDelete() == true }">
                      <td data-bind="attr : {'disabled' : (ForDelete() == true)}, event:{ change: $parent.contactWithFamilyModified} ">
                        <select class="form-control input-sm" id="contact" data-bind="value : FamilyAndCustudyId,
                                                    options: $parent.contactSelectList,
                                                    optionsText: 'Text',
                                                    optionsValue: 'Value', attr : {'disabled' :  (ForDelete() == true || !Editable)}, event:{ click: $parent.contactWithFamilyModified}"></select>
                      </td>

                      <td style="position: relative;">
                        <div class="date datetimepicker">
                          <input type="text" id="DateOfContact" class="form-control" data-bind="datePicker: DateOfContact, attr : {'disabled' :  (ForDelete() == true || !Editable)}, event:{ click: $parent.contactWithFamilyModified }">
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td style="position: relative;">
                        <div class="date datetimepicker">
                          <input type="text" id="TimeOfContact" class="form-control" data-bind="timePicker: TimeOfContact, attr : {'disabled' :  (ForDelete() == true || !Editable)}, event:{ click: $parent.contactWithFamilyModified }">
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td data-bind="text: UserName"></td>
                      <td>
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" form="Remark" data-bind="value: Remark, event:{ click: $parent.contactWithFamilyModified} , attr : {'disabled' : (ForDelete() == true || !Editable)}"></textarea>
                      </td>

                      <td class="action-column">
                        <div class="row-delete fa fa-share icon-flip" title="@SharedResources.Index.Undo" style="color: #096224; cursor: pointer;" data-bind="click: $parent.contactWithFamilyUndoRemove, visible: ForDelete() == true"></div>
                        <div class="row-delete fa fa-minus-circle icon-delete" title="@SharedResources.Index.Delete" data-bind="click: Editable && $parent.active() != 3 ? $parent.contactWithFamilyRemove : null, visible:  $parent.contactWithFamilyRemove, visible: ForDelete() == false, css:{'icon-disabled': Editable == false || $parent.active() == 3}"
                          style="color: #9E0101;cursor: pointer;"></div>
                      </td>

                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <ul class="pagination pagination-sm" style="margin: 0">
                      <li data-bind="css: { disabled:  contactWithFamilyCurrentPage() == 1 }, visible: contactWithFamilyTotalPages() > 0" class="page-link disabled">
                        <a data-bind="click: contactWithFamilyCurrentPage() > 1 ? contactWithFamilyRefreshData.bind($data, 1, null) : null, style: { cursor: contactWithFamilyCurrentPage() == 1 ? 'not-allowed' : 'pointer' }">&laquo;</a>
                      </li>
                      <li data-bind="css: { disabled:  contactWithFamilyCurrentPage() == 1 }, visible: contactWithFamilyTotalPages() > 0" class="page-link disabled">
                        <a data-bind="click: contactWithFamilyCurrentPage() > 1 ? contactWithFamilyRefreshData.bind($data, contactWithFamilyCurrentPage()-1, null) : null, style: { cursor: contactWithFamilyCurrentPage() == 1 ? 'not-allowed' : 'pointer' }">&lsaquo;</a>
                      </li>
                      <!-- ko foreach: new Array(contactWithFamilyTotalPages()) -->
                      <li class="page-item" data-bind="css: { active:  $index()+1 == $parent.contactWithFamilyCurrentPage() }, visible: $index()+1 < $parent.contactWithFamilyCurrentPage()+3 && $index()+1 > $parent.contactWithFamilyCurrentPage()-3">
                        <a href="#" class="page-link" data-bind="text: $index()+1, click: $parent.contactWithFamilyRefreshData.bind($data,$index()+1, null)"></a>
                      </li>
                      <!-- /ko -->
                      <li data-bind="css: { disabled:  contactWithFamilyCurrentPage() == contactWithFamilyTotalPages() }, visible: contactWithFamilyTotalPages() > 0 " class="page-link">
                        <a data-bind="click: contactWithFamilyCurrentPage() < contactWithFamilyTotalPages() ? contactWithFamilyRefreshData.bind($data, contactWithFamilyCurrentPage()+1, null) : null, style: { cursor: contactWithFamilyCurrentPage() == contactWithFamilyTotalPages() ? 'not-allowed' : 'pointer' }">&rsaquo;</a>
                      </li>
                      <li data-bind="css: { disabled:  contactWithFamilyCurrentPage() == contactWithFamilyTotalPages() }, visible: contactWithFamilyTotalPages() > 0 " class="page-link">
                        <a data-bind="click: contactWithFamilyCurrentPage() < contactWithFamilyTotalPages() ? contactWithFamilyRefreshData.bind($data, contactWithFamilyTotalPages(), null) : null, style: { cursor: contactWithFamilyCurrentPage() == contactWithFamilyTotalPages() ? 'not-allowed' : 'pointer' }">&raquo;</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <span class="pull-right"> @SharedResources.Index.Record <span data-bind="text: contactWithFamilyTotalItems"></span> </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    }
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the rules of the [Bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#how-it-works). From the docs...

> "Rows are wrappers for columns... In a grid layout, content must be
>   placed within columns and only columns may be immediate children of
>   rows."

`row` is *only* used to contain columns (`col-*`) and not other elements such as the card.

```
<container>
  <row>
    <col-12>
      <card/>
    </col>
    <col-12>
      <card/>
    </col>
    <col-12>
      <card/>
    </col>
  </row>
</container>
```

***or,***

```
<container>
  <row>
    <col-12>
      <card/>
    </col>
  </row>
  <row>
    <col-12>
      <card/>
    </col>
  </row>
  <row>
    <col-12>
      <card/>
    </col>
  </row>
</container>
```